# Paying for crawlers on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, web-crawler

Yesterday my app has been visited 35 times by HUMANS. It seems however that a machine was crawling the website. I was overquota in a few hours (mostly frontend instance hours).

Today i pay max 5USD per day. For 35 real people it seems way too much.

I dont feel really good paying for crawlers that block the access to my website to regular users. 2 questions for you guys :

1. Is it normal that it happens?
2. What can i do to invest money in the real users instead of crawlers ? (and i am not talking about not referencing my app)

app : www.conceptstore.me

Comment: Note of course you're unlikely ever to get any humans if you don't let the crawlers index your site.

Comment: In what way were you "over quota"? Bandwidth? Do your usage stats indicate the number of crawlers you received across the same time?

Comment: The App Engine logs record user agents, so if they are well-behaved crawlers they should identify themselves as such, and then you should be able to analyse the logs to answer how many crawler hits you received. See my Stack Overflow answer on how to understand log files downloaded from App Engine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's not necessarily necessary to let them index the whole site - only the most interesting pages, might be enough.

Answer (score 3):

A well-behaved crawler should:

- follow the rules in `/robots.txt` - so upload one. This alone should be enough.
- provide a distinct `User-Agent` HTTP request header - so look at the User Agents automatically recorded in the App Engine logs, then return error pages for User-Agents you don't like.